# Cannot deploy laravel using deployer

Tags: php, laravel, deployer

Environment:

```
Local = Windows 11
Server = Ubuntu 22 (AWS EC2)
```

I copied by id_rsa.pub file to ubuntu authorized keys and can ssh into ubuntu server. The *ubuntu* user is the owner of the directory where I want to deploy.

I'm trying to deploy my laravel application to nginx on ubuntu.

```
extension=sockets
```

is uncommented on both the environments.

When I try to run:

```
\vendor\bin\dep deploy
```

i get this error:

[image]

Since I can ssh into server, security should not be an issue.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the permissions